# Visual Studio 2012: UML Class Diagram and Template Bindings

Tags: visual-studio-2012, uml

Has someone successfully managed to model a class realizing an interface which has a template parameter?

I created an interface, added a template parameter T: Class, then I added a class with an inheritance-dependency to the interface.
Now the docs say that I have to add a template binding to the realizing class to specify which type should be bound to the interface's template parameter T: Class.
But the template binding property of my class is empty ("None" is the only item I get).

Does anyone know how to model this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and the only solution that I've found is there: [Visual Studio UML Class Diagram & Modeling of Generic Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330957/visual-studio-uml-class-diagram-modeling-of-generic-types)
It is not realy that what I wanted, but I have not found an better solution.