# Visual Studio UML Class Diagram & Modeling of Generic Types

Tags: visual-studio, uml, modeling, class-diagram

I need to model a concrete generic class inheriting from a base generic class. First, see below:

[image]

ActivityFacade should be implemented this way:

```
public class ActivityFacade : BaseFacade<Activity, int>
{
}
```

How can I model this in a VS2012 UML class diagram? Looking at the diagram, it is obvious that ActivityFacade inherits from BaseFacade, but what's not obvious is the generic type parameters that it is passing in, namely: `Activity` and `int`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add **a new binding class** (`BaseFacade <Activity, int>`) connect it to your parameterized class (`BaseFacade<T, TKey>`) with a **template binding connector** and then specialize your child class (`ActivityFacade`) from the binding class.

[image]

From the OMG UML specification

"A template is a parameterized element ... used to generate other model elements using TemplateBinding relationships. The template parameters for the template signature specify the formal parameters that will be substituted by actual parameters (or the default) in a binding."

**UPDATE:**

The diagram I included is drawn using EA. The same concept can be modeled in Visual Studio UML tool. See the section "[Template types: To use a template type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd409416.aspx#Templates)" in msdn.

Comment: @JohnSaunders The important thing is the concept and not the tool. The diagram in the question is wrong because ActivityFacade should not be inherited from BaseFacade but from BaseFacade<Activity, int>. Here I am showing the concept of modeling Generics in UML. I am sure once the OP knows about TemplateBinding they can find it in visual studio.

Comment: The question was, "How can I model this in a VS2012 UML class diagram". If you can use VS2012 to model this correctly, then you should post that solution. Otherwise, your answer is not relevant to this question.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I believe it is rather a UML question than a tool question and my answer will probably help the OP. I don't understand your approach.

Comment: I believe you read the question incorrectly. The OP clearly asks, "How can I model this in a VS2012 UML class diagram?" Your question answers how he can model this in Sparx EA, a tool which has support for this particular UML notation. VS2012 does not appear to have this notation, so the answer is, "you can't model this in a VS2012 UML class diagram".

Comment: @JohnSaunders Even if you are right, when you see that at least half of the problem is answered, you could suggest an improvement in a comment. It is not like the answer is totally irrelevant. Not to mention even if visual studio does not support this notation, The pure UML is just a dependency with stereotype <<bind>>.

Comment: I told you why I downvoted. I believe your answer is 0% relevant to the question that was asked. If the OP had indicated that he didn't know how to model that in _any_ tool, then your question might have had some relevance. As presently written, it is not an answer to the question at all, and should actually be deleted.

Comment: @JohnSaunders OK I will delete the answer if the OP finds it 0% helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be glad to remove my downvote if you will follow the steps in the link you provided and add a screen shot of the result. It would also be valuable if you were to compare the two tools with respect to this particular task.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks for your suggestion but answer is complete as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Please don't delete it. I need to take a look at this. Thank you for trying @jurgenreza, I will let you know how I get on with this later today.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I appreciate your wanting to keep the answers relevant, but in this case jurgenreza did indeed give me exactly what I needed.. especially with the update. Please realize that sometimes the OP doesn't know exactly what to ask for.. just because I said in VS doesn't mean that I DO in fact know how to do it in some other UML tool. In this case, I mentioned VS because that is what I am using and wanted to know how to do it with that tool.. but any tips given about UML in general are very relevant indeed.

Comment: What a great discussion. I feel it really could have gone either way. I was gripped all the way to the thrilling conclusion!