# How to draw UML class diagram for C++ Template based code?(like TMP)

Tags: c++, templates, uml, instantiation, modeling

I draw UML for C++ as the book **UML distilled** teaches.

Before I study Template Programming the book was enough.
But while I am studying Template Programming including Template Meta Programming, I finally met this problem.

- Are there any known methods to draw instantiation of templates?
- Any best method to express the instantiation of templates?

https://github.com/Jeonghum/tmplguide/tree/master/inherit

From this page you can find a UML diagram I drew for

inherit/namedtmpl.cpp

This is an example of the book, C++ Templates - The Complete Guide
If you could explain taking this as an example it would be the best.

I use StarUML.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860501/what-is-the-correct-way-to-represent-template-classes-with-uml

Comment: Also This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330957/visual-studio-uml-class-diagram-modeling-of-generic-types/15350759#15350759

Comment: Thank you I learned a lot from both questions. @jurgenreza Thank you your explanation helps me also.

Comment: You could upvote if it helped you. Just saying :)

Comment: @jurgenreza I wanted to upvote it but I need more reputation. Now I only have 6 points.

Comment: Not that important, no worries. I only said that because a guy downvoted without a good reason. (read the comments, the discussion is so funny)

Comment: @jurgenreza I've already read the discussion and that's why I wanted to upvote it. And I totally agree with you.

Comment: I earned 19 points so that I can vote up your answer. Thank you for your kindness.